# Should I Use Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I am using Oracle 11g2 and we are having a schema where few tables are having more than 100 million rows (some of them are Varchar2 100 bytes). And we have to frequently do the LIKE based search on those tables. Sometimes we need to join the tables also. Insert / Updates are also happening very frequently for such tables (1000 insert / updates per second) by other applications.

So my question is, for my User Interface, should I use Apache Solr to let user search on these tables instead of SQL queries? I have tried SQL and it is really slow (considering amount of data I am having in my database).

My requirements are,

1. Result should come faster and it should be accurate.
2. It should have the latest data.

Can you suggest if I should go with Apache Solr, or another solution for my problem ?

EDIT : Should I consider Cassandra ? Is it having joins between tables ? Is it having LIKE based search or VARCHAR items of DB ?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Hibernate Search for your requirement. You can use [This link](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) to get started. As you are using tables for your application, you will have lot of facilities like ORM and also Full Text Search through this module. If you want to use Apache Solr, you may have to make necessary code to sync data from your database to Apache Solr Synchronization.

Hope, this may help you

Thanks

Comment: Hi Piyas, Since we are not using Hibernate in our application, I don't know how easy it will be to use Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Solr in your case and you will get the data faster and accurate. About the latest...there would be some lag there...
as data needs to added/updated in solr index.

I have used Solr in my application...(I have used DataImportHandler)
I am updating the Solr index after 20 mins...
that means there is 20 mins lag for the latest update in the database.

But users are fine with it as its faster than Oracle search ...:)
Its been three years... its working fine and there is no issue with it.

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Let's say if Solr indexes are constantly getting updated, is there any problem searching on them at the same time ? Is there any blocking methods / locks being used which doesn't allow reading and writing from Solr at the same time ?

Comment: @pratikthaker : Yes I had the lock issue when I was working on it...I have used the solr 3.3...And for the same reason...i.e. to avoid the lock issue i have kept the lag of 20 min...but I need to check hows the thing with newer version i.e. Solr 5.0

Comment: Thanks. Because I may not be able to have any lag time. So if the locking problem is still there or not is important for me.

Comment: @pratikthaker: I suggest you can go for SolrCloud, which supports near real-time actions...

Comment: here is the link for more information on solrCloud https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud